# Emonlib+ADS1115+ESP32+Arduino Function Pointer

Tags: function-pointers, esp32, adc

I have tried to contact the original designer for the ADS1115->EmonLib adaptation, but unfortunately his Github page has no contact information. I have also tried asking on the OpenEnergyMonitor forum and I get "Contact the person who made the changes".

So, I've come here in the hopes that the knowledgeable folk here can help me out.

Situation:
I have an ESP32 that I'm going to be using to monitor my energy consumption of my home. Because I will be monitoring several circuits I need lots of sensors. The ESP32 only has a 12-bit ADC and I'm limited to only a few sensors. Also limits future expansion if needed.

So here comes the ADS1115, which is a 16-bit ADC, but it uses I2C. Unfortunately, the EmonLib was designed to use onboard ADC, and not through an I2C device. So after doing some digging around, I found this modification to allow the ADS1115 to be used:
https://github.com/PaulWieland/EmonLib/
However, Paul Wieland is not able to be contacted through github.

Ok, so if I wanted to use only 1 ADS1115, I could just use his code as stock, which is this:

```
// In this example we will use an ADS1115 breakout board instead of the Arduino's local analog inputs
// This is especially useful for nodemcu/esp8266 users who only have a single analog input
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_ADS1015.h>

// EmonLibrary examples openenergymonitor.org, Licence GNU GPL V3
#include <EmonLib_I2C.h>       // Include Emon Library

EnergyMonitor emon1;        // Create an instance
Adafruit_ADS1115 ads;          // Create an instance of the ADS1115 object

// Make a callback method for reading the pin value from the ADS instance
int ads1115PinReader(int _pin){
  return ads.readADC_SingleEnded(_pin);
}
void setup()
{  
  emon1.inputPinReader = ads1115PinReader; // Replace the default pin reader with the customized ads pin reader
  emon1.current(1, 111.1);             // Current: input pin, calibration.
}

void loop()
{
  double Irms = emon1.calcIrms(1480);  // Calculate Irms only
  
  Serial.print(Irms*230.0);         // Apparent power
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(Irms);          // Irms
}
```

This compiles just fine. Though I am kinda confused as to how to select the "pin" of the ADS.

In the emonlib.cpp he added this code:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Constructor. Set the pinReader to the default pin reader method
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EnergyMonitor::EnergyMonitor()
{
  this->inputPinReader = defaultInputPinReader;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// By default we just call Arduino's analogRead
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int EnergyMonitor::defaultInputPinReader(int _pin)
{
  return analogRead(_pin);
}
```

And changed this:

```
startV = analogRead(inPinV);
```

to:

```
startV = (this->inputPinReader)(inPinV);
```

and a few other spots where he made the adjustment using "this->".
And in the emonlib.h he added this to the Public section:

```
EnergyMonitor(); 

typedef int (*inputPinReaderMethod) (int _pin);
inputPinReaderMethod inputPinReader;

static int defaultInputPinReader(int _pin);
```

Now, for a single ADS1115, I think this works. At least the code compiles. But I need to use 4 ADS1115's as I'll need to be able to monitor up to 16 circuits. I can't for the life of me figure out how to add an array of ADS's to an array of emonlib's.

I tried doing this:

```
EnergyMonitor emon1[4];        // Create an instance
Adafruit_ADS1115 ads[4];          // Create an instance of the ADS1115 object

// Make a callback method for reading the pin value from the ADS instance
int ads1115PinReader(int _channel, int _pin){
  return ads[1].readADC_SingleEnded(_pin);
}
void setup()
{  
  emon1[1].inputPinReader = ads1115PinReader; // Replace the default pin reader with the customized ads pin reader
  emon1[1].current(1, 111.1);             // Current: input pin, calibration.
}

void loop()
{
  double Irms = emon1[1].calcIrms(1480);  // Calculate Irms only
  
  Serial.print(Irms*230.0);         // Apparent power
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(Irms);          // Irms
}
```

but then I get this error:

```
Emon_ADS_Test:18:27: error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)(int, int)' to 'EnergyMonitor::inputPinReaderMethod {aka int (*)(int)}' [-fpermissive]

   emon1[1].inputPinReader = ads1115PinReader; // Replace the default pin reader with the customized ads pin reader
```

I'm not very advanced in coding, and function pointers just confuse the heck outta me.
So my dilemma is I have several ADS1115's I need to match to the several instances of the EmonLib.
There has to be a separate instance for each wire monitored. On my working model that uses an Arduino Nano I have 2 emonlib variables (emon1, emon2). This works fine as it uses the internal ADC, tho I've found out over time that it is not very accurate and not fast enough or high enough resolution for my needs. (ie. when 0-current is flowing, it shows 50W usage).

What do I need to make a change to make this thing work?

Kori

---

---

[UPDATE 1]
Ok, after some testing, I do still get this:

```
emon[i * j].inputPinReader = ads1115PinReader;
emon[i * j].current(j++, 111.1);  
Unfortunately this throws an error still:

Emon_ADS_Test:21:33: error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)(int, int)' to 'EnergyMonitor::inputPinReaderMethod {aka int (*)(int)}' [-fpermissive]
emon1[i * j].inputPinReader = ads1115PinReader;
```

However, it comes to the function pointer as being a problem.
I use this code:

```
int ads1115PinReader(int _pin){
  return ads.readADC_SingleEnded(_pin);
}
```

It works just fine. However if I do this:

```
int ads1115PinReader(int _channel, int _pin){
  return ads[_channel].readADC_SingleEnded(_pin);
}
```

I get the error above. In the EmonLib_I2C library, the only thing I can think of is in this part:

```
typedef int (*inputPinReaderMethod) (int _pin);
inputPinReaderMethod inputPinReader;

static int defaultInputPinReader(int _pin);
```

not matching up. But even that doesn't make sense. In this line:

```
emon.inputPinReader = ads1115PinReader; // Replace the default pin reader with the customized ads pin reader
```

does that mean that when I call inputPinReader, it "actually" grabs the value from ads1115PinReader instead of the one in the library?

Comment: _pin is the channel. you want to have 16 emon objects and `emon[i*j].current(j, 111.1);` where j is the channel. every ADS1115 must have a different I2C address supplied as parameter of the constructor

Comment: Thanks @Juraj.Ok, so how would I access each ADS1115? I did an example with two for loops to do the 'i' and 'j' variables. it doesn't do 1 - 16 (or 0 - 15). I'm not sure how to access each 4 of the ADC's and each 4 of the pins. Also how would i pass each of the ADC units to the ads1115PinReader call? Doesn't that only do 1 of them? So much of this doesn't seem to make sense to me :(

Comment: Added Update #1

Comment: you could use 4 callback functions

Comment: @Juraj So do something like this: 


`int ads1115PinReader_1(int _pin){return ads1.readADC_SingleEnded(_pin);}
int ads1115PinReader_2(int _pin){return ads2.readADC_SingleEnded(_pin);}
int ads1115PinReader_3(int _pin){return ads3.readADC_SingleEnded(_pin);}
int ads1115PinReader_4(int _pin){return ads4.readADC_SingleEnded(_pin);}`

Where each one calls a different ads channel directly instead of through an array?